# Changes made by submit button via JQuery and JavaScript function do not last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write some text on the document using the document.write() method. Thing is i want this text to be written there when user clicks button, and remain there after the user is done clicking the button. The problem I'm having right now is that the text appears for a moment and then disappears after function is done executing, which is something I do not want nor do not know how to fix it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
       <head>
         <title>Learning JQuery</title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="script.js">
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("input").click(function(){
                for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                  for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    document.write("*");
                  }
                   document.write("<br/>");
                }
                //alert("click to continue");
              });
            });
         </script>
       </head>
       <body>
         <p>Body section of the page</p>
         <form>
           <input type="submit" value="clickMe" />
         </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't use `document.write()` like that. After the page's initial HTML has been rendered, `document.write()` will start the page afresh, blitzing everything that's already there. On rare occasions, that is what you want, but not here I suspect.

Comment: Is this sorta what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/a62uc4jw/

Answer (score 1):

The text "*appears for a moment and then disappears*" because your page refreshes due to the `type="submit"` in you submit button.

You can use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) if you are trying to prevent the page from refreshing.

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("input").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
              for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
                document.write("*");
              }
               document.write("<br/>");
            }
            //alert("click to continue");
          });
        });
```

**[Here is an Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VyU97/313/)**

---

Alternatively, you can rather use a normal button if you are not actually submitting form data:

```
<button id="button">Click Me</button>
```

and then fire the js when the button is clicked: `$("#button").click(function(e){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below,

On the body put a div.

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
```

Then in your code, you can do this inside click

```
  e.preventDefault();
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
      $('#my-div').append("*");
    }
    $('#my-div').append("<br/>");
  }
```

Comment: It is still doing the same thing, changes are made for an instant and then go away. I face the same problem when trying to change bgColor using javascript, background is changed for a moment, once function is done executing everything does back to how it was before it executed.

Comment: add 
e.preventDefault();

before the for loop like M.Doye suggested.